# Exclude folders from Visual Studio 2017 Task List

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem with Task List in Visual Studio 2017. It shows all TODOs from `node_modules` as well and I would like to exclude this folder. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by changing from `Entire Solution` to `Current Project` instead in Task List.

[image]

Comment: You should exclude the dependencies from the IDE itself if you can. VS will bog down relatively quickly once you have a few hundred packages installed.

Comment: seems a little hacky, would be nice to exclude folders instead. Meanwhile, it does work.